# Search for function name ( Javascript )

Tags: javascript

Good day,

Is there any alternative to `arguments.callee.toString().match` to find a function name ? Like make another function with a loop that will search for the name.

All my functions are named :

```
function mthdSearch() {
    console.log("test0")
};

function funkA() {
    console.log("test1");
}


function funkB() {
    console.log("test2");
}
```

Comment: Try to put all of them to an object and use [Object.getOwnPropertyNames()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames)

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Take note, that `arguments.callee` is deprecated and removed in strict mode: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee

Comment: You should be more specific about what you want to do. Do you want to test if a function for a given name exists? In this case—and in case there is a global object—globally declared functions are accessible from the global object. I.e. `function f() {console.log("call to 'f'");}` will be accessible on the `window` object (`window.f()` will result in a print to the console).

Comment: @FK82 , i'm a newbie in our company and i was given a task to find out if it is possible to search for function names and lets say write them in `console.log` . I have found  `arguments.callee` , but u have to write it in each function ? And as Kuba told , it is deprecated in strict mode.

Comment: @KirillVorobjov From a general perspective, this is impossible because of scope. This is a counter example: https://jsfiddle.net/fqb8ukz5/ . As you can see, if you are outside of the scope of the anonymous function, you cannot access the functions named `f` and `h` and thus cannot access their names.

Comment: @FK82 Interesting. Thank you for the explaining .

Comment: @KirillVorobjov My pleasure. Does this answer your question? I suppose you're looking for a JavaScript technique to store a collection of functions. In that case you should look into patterns for *object oriented JavaScript* (here's a good read to get started: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects).

Comment: @FK82 Yes , i will look in to JavaScript Objects . Once again thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in my comment, this is impossible from a general perspective.

You can construct a counter example by declaring functions *locally* (i.e. within *local scope*) of another function and then try to access the declared functions by name outside of the scope of that function:

```js
(function() {
 function f() {console.log("f")}
  var g = function g() {console.log("g");};
  h = function h() {console.log("h");};
  f();
  g();
  h();
})();

try {f();}
catch(e) {console.log(e.message);}

try {g();}
catch(e) {console.log(e.message);}

try {h();}
catch(e) {console.log(e.message);}
```

As you can see, only `h` is accessible outside of the scope of the anonymous function, because it was declared globally (by omitting the `var` keyword).

---

If you're looking for a technique to store a collection of functions and access them by name, use an *object oriented JavaScript* pattern ([MDN introduction to object oriented JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects)).